# Update HTML object rapidly with a C# variable

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

What is a good way to display a rapidly updated value in a c# object, in a website?

Lets say i have the code below running in an c# application deployed in Azure for example. (through Visual Studio.)

(not complete code..)

```
int displayThisAsFastAsPossibleInHMTML;

while(true)
{
  for(int i = 0; i > 1000000; i++)
  {
    displayThisAsFastAsPossibleInHMTML = i;
  }
}
```

And i want to (with JavaScript) update a single paragraph in a webpage:

displayThisAsFastAsPossibleInHMTML

Could you discuss this process a bit and how to achieve a fast update frequence of the C# variable to the website.

Thank you for your time!
Kind Regards
Gustav

Comment: To have a page within a browser update the page with a value from the server you options are Ajax polling to pull the value or a persistent WebSocket connection, the latter being the more performant of the two.

Comment: Take a look at [Asp.Net SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started)